# Image taken through camera intent in portrait mode displays in landscape and vice versa

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, picasso

When I open the camera and take the image it is displayed in opposite mode of which was taken in. Portrait in landscape and vice versa. Im using Picasso library to load the image. Does anyone knows why is it happening? My goal is to display images in mode in which they were originally taken. Here is the code.

```
    override  fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == IMAGE_CAPTURE_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {


            val bitmap = uriToBitmap(cameraUri!!)

            Picasso.get().load(Uri.parse(getRightAngleImage(cameraUri.toString()))).into(mBinding.imgPreview)
            gpuImg.setImage(bitmap)
            viewModel.prepareImagePreview(cameraUri!!)


        }
    } 

  private fun uriToBitmap(selectedFileUri: Uri): Bitmap1? {
        try {
            val parcelFileDescriptor = contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(selectedFileUri, "r")
            val fileDescriptor: FileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor!!.fileDescriptor
            val image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor)
            parcelFileDescriptor.close()
            return image
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return null
    }
    private fun getRightAngleImage(photoPath: String): String? {
        try {
            val ei = ExifInterface(photoPath)
            val orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(TAG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATION_NORMAL)
            var degree = 0
            degree = when (orientation) {
                ORIENTATION_NORMAL -> 0
                ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90 -> 90
                ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180 -> 180
                ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270 -> 270
                ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED -> 0
                else -> 90
            }
            return rotateImage(degree, photoPath)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return photoPath
    }

    private fun rotateImage(degree: Int, imagePath: String): String? {
        if (degree <= 0) {
            return imagePath
        }
        try {
            var b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath)
            val matrix = Matrix()
            if (b.width > b.height) {
                matrix.setRotate(degree.toFloat())
                b = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    b, 0, 0, b.width, b.height,
                    matrix, true
                )
            }
            val fOut = FileOutputStream(imagePath)
            val imageName = imagePath.substring(imagePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
            val imageType = imageName.substring(imageName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1)
            val out = FileOutputStream(imagePath)
            if (imageType.equals("png", ignoreCase = true)) {
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out)
            } else if (imageType.equals("jpeg", ignoreCase = true) || imageType.equals(
                    "jpg",
                    ignoreCase = true
                )
            ) {
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out)
            }
            fOut.flush()
            fOut.close()
            b.recycle()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return imagePath
    }
```

Comment: `Picasso.get().load(Uri.parse(getRightAngleImage(cameraUri.toString())))` Why not: `Picasso.get().load(cameraUri)` ?

Comment: `gpuImg.setImage(bitmap)` Further you are also messing around with a bitmap here. Why? Confusing! If it has nothing to do with it then remove that code please.

Comment: gpuImg is to set image to gpu view so I can apply filters on (which is working), getRightAngleImage is to rotate the image if needed (not working)

Comment: You have not reacted on my first comment. Nor on the orhers.